# Post to a page wall that I'm not admin

Tags: facebook, post, permissions, publish

I created an app to post to pages the user chooses. How can I direct the message to a page Wall on behalf of the user? From my tests the post is sent, but the page can't see it and  the page is not notified either.

I have OAuth extended Permissions of publish_stream, what else do I need to my post not being invisible?

I will try to clarify the problem in details:

1- I send a post to a Facebook page that is not mine, I'm just a normal user, via application that ask for publish_stream, read_stream permissions.

2- I verify the page logging as admin but no notification is delivered and I can't see the post on my Wall.

3-If I log as the sender user I can see the post on page Wall, it looks like the post is private and just the sender user can see It. If I try to recover the post via Graph API using the same user it returns false.

4- Only the users who has the app installed can see the post on page wall.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what didn't work ? Using Graph API, it is possible to post to a Page -https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts

Comment: I tried to clarify is it better now? Is it possible to post to a page that I'm not the owner?

Comment: Resuming: Only me can see the post, the page that receives it can't see it.

Comment: What are the page’s settings like – concerning who is allowed to post to their wall/timeline?

Comment: Any person can post to their wall. If I post with the same user that used the app directly by Facebook the post appears normally.